# Медленный Google Play и SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, google-play, android-shared-preferences

Написал приложение с `minSdkVersion 14`. В приложении реализовал сохранение настроек в `SharedPreferences`, а также есть `SQLite`.

Работает все так:

- юзер грузит приложение с `Google Play`
- `Google Play` устанавливает его. `Android` показывает в `StatusBar`, сто приложение установлено, но ярлыка на рабочем/домашнем столе нет. Если жать на уведомление в `StatusBar` или на приложение в меню смартфона, то оно запустится с уже сохраненным первым запуском. А так не должно быть.

Логика работы следующая:

1. Запускаем приложение
2. Читаем `SharedPreferences`
3. проверяем на первый запуск, если его не было, то парсим данные и пишем в БД, потом сохраняем в `SharedPreferences` первое посещение.

Но оно все сбивается.

На `Android` 4.1.2 через менеджер приложений данный приложения стираются, и потом можно приложение запустить ярлыком и будет то, что я запрограммировал.
На `Android` 5.1.1 такое номер не прошел.
На `Android` 6.0 такой номер прошел, но в интересном порядке: стираем данные приложения, удаляем приложение. Потом устанавливаем и все ок.

Можно ли как-то это исправить ? Или есть код, который отработается, если приложение удаляется ? То есть можно затереть за собой данные приложения после его удаления ?

**UPD0**

```
boolean hasVisited = shared_prefer.getBoolean(APP_VISITED, false);
if (!hasVisited) {
    // ... необходимые действия        
    // 4. set appVisited
    setAppVisited();
}

// метод setAppVisited()
private static void setAppVisited() {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = shared_prefer.edit();
    // ... 
    editor.putBoolean(APP_VISITED, true);   // записать первое посещение
    editor.apply();
}
```

Comment: По словесному описанию никто вам ничего путнего не скажет.не работает код - нужен код. Как в преференсах первый запуск определяете, манифест и все другое, что связано с проблемой. Причем здесь МЕДЛЕННЫЙ гугл плэй?

Comment: @pavlofff, выложил работу с SP, зачем манифест то ?  Goole Play здесь при том, что ранее он мне быстро создавал ярлыки для приложений, а сейчас нужно ждать еще секунд 5. И это при том, что смартфон полностью разгружен от фоновых приложений.